# blinking left pane in nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, ubuntu-gnome

I have 3 more HD to mount but after a reboot, this part of the panel from network to the end of the panel is constantly blinking no matter if I mount those 3 discs or not.
How could I fix this?
Using Ubuntu Gnome, 16.04.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this happened after deleting a massive number of files in Nautilus and sending them to the Trash bin. I couldn't dig further or find another explanation. I stopped having that behaviour to avoid crashes.